# Insert data to itab in Debugger

Tags: debugging, abap

How can I insert rows in a table that is empty,through debug just to see the result of my code?[image]

Comment: Right click, you will see Change Table Content menu.

Comment: Yes but I cant insert a row,only edit

Comment: Do you have the necessary authorization? It should be possible to insert a row

Comment: There is no separate authorization for itab editing, if one have permissions for editing variable contents, he should also be able to insert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the internal table can be edited in the current debug context you have two options:

1, In the tool window on the right there's the services menu. You can find table tools there and add a new row:

[image]

2, Right click in the table and choose **Change Table Content** item:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You (or your BASIS-team more likely) should also check your developing permissions in [S_DEVELOP](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SMAUTH/S_DEVELOP) authorization object. There is **OBJTYPE** `DEBUG` there, which has three different activities for different debugging levels

- `Activity 03`: Display
- `Activity 02`: Changing values of fields and the function Debugging->Goto statement
- `Activity 01`: Displaying in System Programs and Kernel Debugging

As you guess, you should possess `Activity 02` in your authorization profile to be able to edit variables.

Comment: Thanks for your info,it helps but not the answer to the question above!